# Error while installing radio in Xperia m running cyanogenmod 12

Tags: cyanogenmod

After completing installation of CM12 in my Xperia M C1904 , I found that there is no signal capturing by the device,but some times it does.
I doubt it is be the issue with baseband . So i had a try installing zip file containing modem.img according to the post
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2703161

But it is not installing
,showing an error in the screen like this

```
E:footer is wrong
E:signature verification failed
```

I did this in the cyanogen recovery since after the cm12 installation I'm unable to get into cwm recovery.
Is there any probable way to fix this issue?

thanks in advance

Comment: @Matthew Read Thankyou it worked and now my phone is gettingsignal

Comment: Glad to hear it!  I've turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally only a stock recovery would be attempting signature verification.

I would suggest reinstalling ClockworkMod Recovery and attempting to flash the modem again.